# mod $p$ irreducibility test over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, polynomial-rings

I have a question about the following result:

If $f ∈ \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is primitive and there is a prime $p$ not dividing the leading coefficient of $f$ such that $f$ is irreducible in $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})[X]$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

My question: Does this result still hold if $p$ is composite? I have looked at a few proofs of this statement and I’m not sure how the fact that $p$ is prime is being used. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297670/in-mod-p-irreducibility-test-for-zt-need-p-be-prime), and I suppose there are more.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Obviously we require that the leading coefficient is a unit

Comment: Yes, but still the point is that then $\Bbb Z/n$ has zero divisors.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  No the point is that we need to restrict to polynomials whose leading coefficient is a unit and that it works well.

Comment: So the result does not hold as the OP wanted, but only with monic polynomials? The other linked question also had this problem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But the goal is to share some knowledge, not to propagate the fake news that we *need* $p$ prime as in so many questions. We don't need $p$ prime, we need to restrict to unit leading coefficient, that's the right answer.

Comment: But it is also interesting to discuss the case where the leading coefficient is not a unit. I wouldn't call this "fake news". It is just different, as $x=(3x+2)(2x+3)$ modulo $6$ shows.

Comment: I am interested in the case where $f$ is primitive. Perhaps $p$ being prime is needed to ensure that the units of $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})[X]$ are precisely the units of $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ ...

Comment: Suppose $f = g h$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, with $deg(g), deg(h) < deg(f)$. Then $\overline{f} = \overline{g} \overline{h}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})[X]$. If $\overline{g}$ and $\overline{h}$ are both not units, then we are done. Can this step be justified without $p$ being prime?